# ABP API is broken (Cannot read property 'app' of undefined)

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP BOILER PLATE template under MVC5 structure. Here i am getting an exception in the login page such as:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?v=637329960929431434 net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Once I logged into my system, I have encountered an error in my console as:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null
    at Canvas.resize (jquery.flot.js:135)
    at new Canvas (jquery.flot.js:114)
    at setupCanvases (jquery.flot.js:1313)
    at new Plot (jquery.flot.js:707)
    at Function.$.plot (jquery.flot.js:3146)
    at initRealTimeChart (Index.js:20)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Index.js:12)
    at fire (jquery.js:3182)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3312)
```

I cant do any CRUD operations....
Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: check for the API Logs, that will help